# Creating flat terrain with triangle strips

Tags: c++, opengl, gl-triangle-strip

I am asking for some help with drawing a flat terrain using triangle strips. If this is the correct way to do it?

So far i managed to create vertex and index arrays, debugged it couple of times and it seems to generate correct values.

At first I tried drawing with degenerate triangles, but I read somewhere that it's an outdated way and I should rather switch to a primitive restart option.

**NOTE THAT THIS NOT THE EXACT WAY MY PROJECT IS SET UP... I just copied the necessery code**

Here is the code for terrain generation:

```cpp
this->terrainSize = width * height;
unsigned int numRows = height - 1;                        //!NUMBER OF ROWS OF TRIANGLE STRIPS
unsigned int numColumns = width - 1;                      //!Number of columns of strips
unsigned int numVerticiesPerRow = 2 * width;              //!NUMBER OF VERTICIES PER EVERY ROW
unsigned int numIndPerRow = numColumns * 2 + 2;           //!Number of indices per row
unsigned int numOfStrips = numRows - 1;                   //!Number of splits, after every row


this->numVertices = terrainSize * 8;                        
this->numIndices = numRows * numIndPerRow + numOfStrips;   //!total number of indices


std::vector<float> vertexArray (numVertices);
float* vertexPointer = vertexArray.data();            
float* vertexPointer2 = vertexArray.data();
for( int row = 0; row < height; row++ )              //!Z AXIS
{
    for( int col = 0; col < width; col++ )           //!X AXIS
    {
        float x = (float) ( col - width / 2 );       
        float z = (float) ( row - height / 2 );

        //?Positions
        *vertexPointer = x; ++vertexPointer;           //?1
        *vertexPointer = 0.0f; ++vertexPointer;       //?2
        *vertexPointer = z; ++vertexPointer;          //?3

        //?Normals (lightning)
        *vertexPointer = 0.0f; ++vertexPointer;        //?4 
        *vertexPointer = 1.0f; ++vertexPointer;        //?5 
        *vertexPointer = 0.0f; ++vertexPointer;       //?6

        //?Texture Coordinates
        *vertexPointer = x; ++vertexPointer;           //?7
        *vertexPointer = z; ++vertexPointer;          //?8
        }
    }

//?GENERATE INDICIES
std::vector<unsigned int> indexArray (numIndices);
unsigned int* indexPointer = indexArray.data();
unsigned int* indexPointer2 = indexArray.data();
for( int row = 0; row < height - 1; row++ )   //!Z AXIS
{
    for( int col = 0; col < width; col++ )   //!X AXIS
    {
        *indexPointer = ( row * height ) + col; ++indexPointer;       
        *indexPointer = (( row + 1 )* height ) + col; ++indexPointer;

    }
    if( row < height - 2 )                   **//!Add 0xFFFF on the end of each row** 
    {
        *indexPointer = 0xFFFF; ++indexPointer;             
    }
}
```

```cpp
//Pack the data into vertex struct
unsigned int i;
for( i = 0; i < this->numVertices; i=i+0 )
{
    Vertex vertex;
    glm::vec3 vector;

    vector.x = vertexArray[i++];
    vector.y = vertexArray[i++];
    vector.z = vertexArray[i++];
    vertex.Position = vector; 

    vector.x = vertexArray[i++];
    vector.y = vertexArray[i++];
    vector.z = vertexArray[i++];
    vertex.Normal = vector;

    glm::vec2 vec;

    vec.x = vertexArray[i++];
    vec.y = vertexArray[i++];
    vertex.TexCords = vec;

    this->vertexStruct.push_back( vertex );
}
for( i = 0; i < this->numIndices; i++ )
{
    this->indexVector.push_back( indexArray[i] );
}
```

```cpp
//Bind VertexArray
VAO.Create();

//Bind VertexBuffer
VBO.Create( vertexArray, numVertices);

//Bind IndexBuffer
IBO.Create( indexArray, numIndices );

//? DEFINE HOW SHOULD THE GPU SHOULD READ THE DATA FROM VERTEX BUFFER
//Position
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( Vertex ), (GLvoid*) offsetof( Vertex, Position ) );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
//Normal
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( Vertex ), (GLvoid*) offsetof( Vertex, Normal ) );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
//Texcoord
glVertexAttribPointer( 2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( Vertex ), (GLvoid*) offsetof( Vertex, TexCords ) );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
```

```
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE ); //?ENABLE WIREFRAME
glEnable( GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART );
glPrimitiveRestartIndex( 0xFFFF );
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, this->numVertices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, this->indexArray );
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL ); //?DISABLE WIREFRAME
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If this is the correct way to do it,because when I run the project it just shows the black screen

Comment: Post-increment works for pointers too!

Comment: In principle yes, but not quite: Your indices are a bit off (`* height` should be `* width`), the index buffer needs to be bound when you set up your VAO, the last parameter in `glDrawElements` should be a `nullptr` in your case and you need to pass the number of indices (not vertices), and your calculation of total indices looks a bit off in general. I would also just use `.push_back()` of the vector instead of fiddling around with pointers.

Comment: Will try switching to vector as an array instead of incrementing pointers cuz truth be told I wasted to much time with them, other than that I will see what I can do to fix it, thank you :D